# NestJs e2e returns 201 created response though required form data is missing, expected 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, end-to-end

I'm trying to write a test that checks if request body does not have proper data, it should return an error, and the status code should be 400. Which I think is by default for nestjs's validator.

This is my contorller,

```js
@Post("register/client-business-manager")
async registerClientBusinessManager(@Body() form: RegisterClientBusinessManager): Promise<any> {
    return { something: "ok" }
}
```

This is my form request class,

```js
export class RegisterClientBusinessManager {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @MaxLength(100)
    @IsString()
    first_name: string

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @MaxLength(100)
    @IsString()
    last_name: string

   // ... other fields
}
```

```js
it("returns 400 if proper data is not given", () => {
        return request(app.getHttpServer())
            .post("/auth/register/client-business-manager")
            .expect(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    })
```

But the response I get,

```sh
 expected 400 "Bad Request", got 201 "Created"

      38 |         return request(app.getHttpServer())
      39 |             .post("/auth/register/client-business-manager")
    > 40 |             .expect(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
         |              ^
      41 |     })
      42 | })
      43 |
```

I'm also using a global validation pipe,

In my main.ts,

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)

app.setGlobalPrefix("api/v1")
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS))
```

On the other hand, making a request from postman gives the proper 400 bad request.

I'm new to nestjs. Why might be the reason for this type of behaviour and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using the `ValidationPipe` and do you normally have it globally bound? If so, how do you bind it?

Comment: I do have validation pipe. I'm using it globally with transform and whitelist to true. @JayMcDoniel

I've added the validation pipe's code to the description.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you've bound the `ValidationPipe` globally in the `main.ts` file's `bootstrap` method. You don't call that method in your test though, so the pipe never gets bound and you need to still call `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())` in the test file. Another option would be to use the `APP_PIPE` global provider and bind the pipe globally that way. In your `AppModule` (or any other module honestly) you can do the following:

```js
@Module({
  imports: ServerImports,
  providers: [...ServerProviders, 
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useValue: new ValidationPipe(validationPipeOptions),
    }
  ],
  controllers: ServerControllers,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now whenever you use the `AppModule`, whether it is in a test or in the `main.ts` you have the pipe globally bound and you don't need to worry about binding it again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the Validation Pipe from NestJs. You can either:

Register a global Validation Pipe in your bootstrap function like this:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  // ...
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  // app.listen(), etc.
}
```

or you can register the ValidationPipe, in using your `@Body` decorator like this:

```
@Post("register/client-business-manager")
async registerClientBusinessManager(@Body(ValidationPipe) form: RegisterClientBusinessManager): Promise<any> {
    return { something: "ok" }
}
```

EDIT: You can also register a pipe at controller level using the `@UsePipes` decorator

Comment: I do have validation pipe. I'm using it globally with transform and whitelist to true.  I've added the validation pipe's code to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake.
I was mistakenly registering the validation pipe after `app.init()`.

So the solution was this,

```
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS))

await app.init()
```

instead of

```
await app.init()
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_PIPE_OPTIONS))
```